# Coloring specified character of String

Tags: java, string, swing, character, foreground

I searched for this issue and I found the below codes, but these codes are for Java-Android. What are the similar codes that I can use with Java

The codes are:

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("mp");  // insert your pattern here
Matcher m = p.matcher("Simple Text, bumping , jumping");
while (m.find()) {
    positions.add(m.start());
}

Spannable spanning = new SpannableString("Simple Text");        
spanning.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),positions.get(i), positions.get(i)+1, 
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    
textview.setText(spanning);
```

Comment: *What are the similar codes that I can use with java Netbeans.* - Netbeans is not a GUI. We have no idea what GUI you are using. Is it Swing? Is it JavaFX? Is it something else.

Comment: Yes, I am using swing .. sorry I didn't specify

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Text Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for Swing basics. If you want to use HTML you use a JEditorPane. If you want styled text you use a JTextPane. The tutorial has examples of both.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I need to change the color for a specific character in a word... This means I have the word (Hello) and with some conditions, the letter (o) should be a different color.

Comment: No, I completely understand. You need to read the tutorial and download the demo code to understand how to do this. Swing is different than Android so you need to do some reading to understand how it is done in Swing. Swing use a `Document` to hold the text and the attributes of the text. You can set attributes for individual characters or for paragraphs of text.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will read the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java Swing?

If yes, you can put `"<html>YOUR TEXT</html>"` with needly customizations for you design.

Put it inside an `new JLabel("<html>YOUR...");` It is the principle of Java graphics design, and today we have the JavaFX that will replace these method of interface programming

Comment: Yes of course I tried, but the problem is with 
`Spannable spanning = new SpannableString("Simple Text");`
it gave me an error with that line.

Comment: SpannableString is an Android class, not a Swing class.

Comment: Yes dear, and my question is, How to get the same method for java swing.

Comment: This is no "same method". You have been given a link to the Swing tutorial which demonstrates how it is done in Swing.

Comment: I edited the answer, bro go learn Java design it is very common.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution.

You can change the colour of the label.

Add this to your jframe or jlabel as you have used in your project.

Thank you

```
Label label = new Label("Your text");
//sets the colour of text
label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
//sets the backround of text
label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```